# How to a check column exits in a table in SQL drill query

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-drill

```
SELECT t1.customerInformation.customerid AS CustomerId
FROM EndUserNotificationHistoryEvent t1
WHERE t1.operationType <> 'DELETE';
```

In this above query where condition should be executed only when operationType column is present in the table. If operationType column is not present where condition is no needed.

Comment: Please include the table definition for `EndUserNotificationHistoryEvent`.  It looks like your question is missing some critical information.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL here, only include the WHERE clause when the column exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT t1.customerInformation.customerid AS CustomerId
FROM EndUserNotificationHistoryEvent t1
WHERE (t1.operationType <> 'DELETE' OR t1.operationType IS NULL)
```

Comment: I tried that but it  throws  Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: DELETE @Thiyagu

Comment: WHERE (CAST(t1.operationType AS VARCHAR(50)) <> 'DELETE' OR t1.operationType IS NULL) - Try this @Kamalraj

Answer (score 1):

For this particular query you may use:

```sql
SELECT t1.customerInformation.customerid AS CustomerId
FROM EndUserNotificationHistoryEvent t1
WHERE t1.operationType <> 'DELETE' OR t1.operationType IS NULL;
```

The addition of the `IS NULL` check to the where clause will effectively turn off the check for delete, should the column be `NULL`.

Comment: I tried that ,but got ** Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: DELETE **error @Tim Biegeleision

Comment: Well you're apparently trying to run some kind of delete, but that's not what your question is asking about.

Comment: When I use t1.operationType <> 'DELETE' that time itsef it throws SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: DELETE @Tim Biegeleision

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the boolean operation, Another approach is to use the `COALESCE` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.CUSTOMERINFORMATION.CUSTOMERID AS CUSTOMERID
  FROM ENDUSERNOTIFICATIONHISTORYEVENT T1
 WHERE COALESCE(T1.OPERATIONTYPE,'NOT DELETE') <> 'DELETE'; 
-- WHEN T1.OPERATIONTYPE IS NULL, CONDITION WILL BE ALWAYS TRUE
```